# How to troubleshoot "Next without for" Compile Error?

Tags: excel, vba

My code has many `If` statements. There are a few `For` loops nested within an outer `For` loop. I get:

```
Compile error: Next without For
```

Is there some editor that will pair the statements and show the disconnect? Is there some method for tracking down an error like this?

Comment: If you just post the code here, someone can easily show you where the problem is.

Comment: Normally properly indenting can help you spot missing `End If` or `End With` or other similar issues in cases like these.

Comment: _Is there some great method for tracking down an error like this?_: yes, Indention.  A great tool to help you with that and much more is [rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an End If statement.  That was my issue.

Thank for the replies. I thought I had indented properly, and I think that going through line by line and checking that would have found my issue.

I ended up finding it by going through and cutting some of the blocks of ifs and loops inside of the big loop until I found the offending section.